# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: discord.py

I tried to make a command that will send the message to the specified channel and get the below error

`Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`

```
@client.command(name="chmsg")
async def _chmsg(ctx):

    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and \
               msg.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send("Message")
    mestoc = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    await ctx.send("Channel id")
    chasend = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    mestoch = str(mestoc.content)
    cha = str(chasend.content)
    channel = client.get_channel(cha)
    await channel.send(f"{mestoch}")
```

Comment: This looks way too complicated for what could be such a simple command. Are you just looking for a command that sends something to a certain channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't have to convert `mestoc.content` as a string as it is already a string
2. You need `cha` as an integer, not as a string so you can get the channel

So your revised code looks like

```
@client.command(name="chmsg")
async def _chmsg(ctx):

    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and \
               msg.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send("Message")
    mestoc = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    await ctx.send("Channel ID")
    chasend = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    mestoch = mestoc.content
    cha = int(chasend.content)
    channel = client.get_channel(cha)
    await channel.send(f"{mestoch}")
```